# How can I use LaTeX math expression with other fonts in matplotlib and ploty?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plotly

I know that any string can be rendered with LaTeX in both matplotlib and plotly. For example, `r$\sqrt{\dfrac{m\sigma^2}{\epsilon}}$` will give correct like below figure link.

[LaTeX rendering in plotly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g81Jw.png)

However, I want to use normal font such as Arial instead of default LaTeX font. Is there any way I can do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try passing font keywords either into the labelling function or into `matplotlib.rc`:

```
In [1]:
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(0, 4*np.pi)
y = 2 * np.sin(np.exp(3/2*x))

fontspecs = {'family': 'Arial',
             'weight': 'bold'}
mpl.rc('font', **fontspecs)  # To set font-specifications globally
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.xlabel(r'$2 * sin(e^{\frac{3}{2} * x})$')
# plt.xlabel(r'$2 * sin(e^{\frac{3}{2} * x})$',  # To just use font settings for this label
#            fontname=fontspecs['family'], fontweight=fontspecs['weight'])

Out [1]:
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It works as I desired. But do you know about how this can be possible in plotly?

Comment: Sorry I don't use plotly